# Subscription is not assignable to NgIterable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**Goal:** I want to display User Data in the Frontend

I have a user model `IPerson` of the following structure:

```
export interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  passwort: string;
}
```

In THE auth Service, I created an observable of this type, which should hold profile information as soon as I `next()` some into it

```
public loggedInUserData = new ReplaySubject<IPerson>();
```

In the profile component, I want to get the latest payload of this observable and store it

```
public profiles$ = this.authService.loggedInUserData.subscribe((res) => {
  return res;
});
```

And finally, I want to display the user data received in HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles$">
  <td>{{ profile.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ profile.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ profile.passwort }}</td>
</tr>
```

**Problem:** I get the following error:

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'

Comment: Do not subscribe in your component. Instead use `async` pipe in your template and it will work: `*ngFor="let profile of profiles$ | async"`

Comment: this worked, but it doesnt help my understanding of why my solution doesnt work. Technically, the async pipe also just subscribes to the observable

Comment: The async pipe passes the emitted value to your ngFor. The way you were doing it you were passing a Subscription object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking that you need [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) rxjs operator to accumulate `IPerson` object as `Observable<IPerson[]>`.

```js
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

public profiles$: Observable<IPerson[]> = this.authService.loggedInUserData
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []));
```

And use `async` pipe to subscribe to the observable.

```
<tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles$ | async">
  <td>{{ profile.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ profile.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ profile.passwort }}</td>
</tr>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-raytav?file=src/app/app.component.ts)